# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Music: Practice & Theory breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         12
Users destroyed                                  26          0
Users deleted                                     3          0
Users contacted                                   9          0
User suspensions lifted early                     1          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           185      1,249
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               42        177
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         97        764
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               56        799
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               143      2,590
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              430      1,548
Tags merged                                       1          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             7          1
Tag synonyms created                              8          0
Questions unprotected                             0          1
Questions reopened                               24          2
Questions protected                              50         35
Questions migrated                               69          1
Questions merged                                  1          0
Questions flagged⁴                               12        810
Questions closed                                847        187
Question flags handled⁴                         281        541
Posts unlocked                                    1          9
Posts undeleted                                  21         47
Posts locked                                     20        190
Posts deleted⁵                                  816      1,002
Posts bumped                                      0        893
Escalations to the CM team                        3          0
Comments undeleted                               76          0
Comments flagged                                 36        505
Comments deleted⁶                             6,009      1,550
Comment flags handled                           329        212
Answers flagged                                 154      1,469
Answer flags handled                          1,364        259
All comments on a post moved to chat             48          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://music.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: What's the question? Lol!

Comment: @luserdroog there is no question here. It is a post by a CM (Community Manager) showing data on the moderation activities on this SE site. It is for our information.